# How many Cohanim and Levi'im worked in the Temple daily?

Tags: number, beis-hamikdash, kohen-priest

How many Cohanim and Levi'im worked in the Temple daily (excluding supporting professions, like preparing woods or oils) and how many of them stayed there for sleep?

Comment: Is the question about weekdays, shabbos or holidays, etc?

Comment: @Loani You tell.